# owl carousel navigation dots change active class smoothly

Tags: jquery, html, css-transitions, owl-carousel

In owl carousel, I want a transition in dots navigation I tried to like this but it's not working.
[image: dots Navigation]

```
 .slider.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    top: -34px;
    left: 40%;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #ffffff;
    margin: 5px 7px;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
    background: transparent;
 }
```

can anyone suggest me how I will achieve this help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: transition on what? on hover?

Comment: @Mr x when active class change i want some transition.i'm using autoplay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Owl Carousel already has `transition` on `dots` but it only set on `opacity`, you should change it to `all`

**Find:**

```
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px 7px;
    background: #D6D6D6;
    display: block;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    transition: opacity .2s ease;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

**Replace With:**

```
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px 7px;
    background: #D6D6D6;
    display: block;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

**Or override this property:**

```
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
   transition: all .2s ease!important;
}
```

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
   transition: all .2s ease!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Husna See snippet , it works fine. what do you expect?

Comment: thanks.but I don't know what might be the problem in my code its not working.

Comment: @Husna I think the problem is your `class` name. Did you try this? `.atsc-slider-s1.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
   transition: all .2s ease!important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
.owl-dot{ 
    &.active{
       span{
            background: $text-color!important;
        }
    }
}
```